# WooCommerce - Print Processing orders

Tags: php, wp-query, templates, woocommerce-offtopic, html

On our WooCommerce webshop we have an PHP page that generates the processing orders. Now I need to show the SKU in the table, but I don't know how to do that :)

Below is an example of the page as it is now:
[image: Example]

This is the PHP template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Print Processing Orders Full
*/
if (!is_user_logged_in() || !current_user_can('manage_options'));
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title><?php _e('Processing Orders'); ?></title>
<style>
    body { background:white; color:black; width: 95%; margin: 0 auto; }
    table { border: 1px solid #000; width: 100%; }
    table td, table th { border: 1px solid #000; padding: 6px; }
    article { border-top: 2px dashed #000; padding: 20px 0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</header>
<section>
<?php 

global $woocommerce;

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'shop_order_status',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array('processing')
                )
            )
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $order_id = $loop->post->ID;

    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    ?>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h2>Order #<?php echo $order_id; ?> &mdash; <time datetime="<?php the_time('c'); ?>"><?php echo the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></time></h2>
        </header>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e('sku', 'woothemes'); ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e('Product', 'woothemes'); ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e('Quantity', 'woothemes'); ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e('Price', 'woothemes'); ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot> 
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; padding-top: 12px;"><?php _e('Subtotal:', 'woothemes'); ?></th>
                    <td style="text-align:left; padding-top: 12px;"><?php echo $order->get_subtotal_to_display(); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php if ($order->order_shipping > 0) : ?><tr>
                    <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e('Shipping:', 'woothemes'); ?></th>
                    <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $order->get_shipping_to_display(); ?></td>
                </tr><?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($order->order_discount > 0) : ?><tr>
                    <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e('Discount:', 'woothemes'); ?></th>
                    <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo woocommerce_price($order->order_discount); ?></td>
                </tr><?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($order->get_total_tax() > 0) : ?><tr>
                    <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e('Tax:', 'woothemes'); ?></th>
                    <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo woocommerce_price($order->get_total_tax()); ?></td>
                </tr><?php endif; ?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e('Total:', 'woothemes'); ?></th>
                    <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo woocommerce_price($order->order_total); ?> <?php _e('- via', 'woothemes'); ?> <?php echo ucwords($order->payment_method); ?></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <?php echo $order->email_order_items_table(); ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <h2><?php _e('Customer details', 'woothemes'); ?></h2>

        <?php if ($order->billing_email) : ?>
            <p><strong><?php _e('Email:', 'woothemes'); ?></strong> <?php echo $order->billing_email; ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($order->billing_phone) : ?>
            <p><strong><?php _e('Tel:', 'woothemes'); ?></strong> <?php echo $order->billing_phone; ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div style="float:left; width: 49%;">

            <h3><?php _e('Billing address', 'woothemes'); ?></h3>

            <p>
                <?php echo $order->get_formatted_billing_address(); ?>
            </p>

        </div>

        <div style="float:right; width: 49%;">

            <h3><?php _e('Shipping address', 'woothemes'); ?></h3>

            <p>
                <?php echo $order->get_formatted_shipping_address(); ?>
            </p>

        </div>

        <div style="clear:both;"></div>

        </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

1. Remove the SKU table header
2. Add `(SKU)` to the *Product* header `Product (SKU)`
3. pass `false, true` in `email_order_items_table` function `$order->email_order_items_table(false, true)`

This is not the visual result you were expecting, but it works and it shows the SKU. The second parameter in `email_order_items_table` indicates whether to show the SKU or not.

Comment: +1 Many thanks! Works perfectly! Only drawback is the placement, but it works that's what matters.